# How to Insert data into a table with sqlmap using its sql-query command

Tags: sql-injection

I'm using sqlmap on a test site and I wanted to modify some of the data inside of a table. Using the switch `--sql-query`.

- What is the correct syntax?

  example: is it `--sql-query="My_query_here"`?
  or maybe it's `--sql-query='myqueryhere'`?
- How would I be able to modify multiple rows of data?

  example: Say I wanted to replace all data with the words. Game Over
- Is it possible to drop in a shell?

Comment: Yeah custom queries execution is possible with SQLMAP but you need DBMS Privileges and also if injection is stacked queries

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most databases do not allow you to just insert data using SQL Injection (Unless of course you are already in an insert query and even then you usually can't control the table name).  You can't simply stack queries,  that is only allowed in Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL and comic books (like [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/)).  You can use a sub-select or union select to access data from another table, and SQLMap is doing this behind the scenes.

SQLMap's real strength is in data exfiltration, and it has some tricks to get RCE.  But, If you want something more complex,  like a multi-staged attack that gives you a shell,  then you need to write a [multi-staged SQLi exploit like this one](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/12510/), which I wrote.  If you want a deeper understanding of security then you need to write exploits to have that experience, take off the training wheels and be man (or woman or whatever).

Comment: Agreed. At a certain point, you have to accept that sqlmap and Havij are toys designed for cheap and easy data exfiltration.

Answer (score 14):

you can take a shell by `--sql-shell` option. For example in Kali:

```
sqlmap -u TARGET -D DBNAME --sql-shell
```

However,

> some web application technologies do not support stacked queries on
>   specic database management systems. For instance, PHP does not
>   support stacked queries when the back-end DBMS is MySQL, but it does
>   support when the back-end DBMS is PostgreSQL.

*from [sqlmap readme](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage)*